# Vim local statusline doesn't set up correctly upon open new window

Tags: vimscript, statusline, original-vim, vim8

I tried to write a small script to give the statusline distinguishable appearance on current and non-current window.

The local active and inactive statuslines are defined by the following code:

- Active `statusline`:

```
function! SttLine_Active(usesimple)
    setl statusline=

    if (!a:usesimple)
        setl statusline+=\%#StatusBlockColour#
        setl statusline+=\ %{g:currentmode[mode()]}\ %0*

        setl statusline+=\%#StatusLineColour#
        setl statusline+=\ %p%%\(%L)\ ≡\ L%l\:%c\ \|%0*

        setl statusline+=\%#StatusFileColour#
        setl statusline+=\ [%{winnr()}]\ %f\ %m%=%0*

        setl statusline+=\%#StatusBlockColour#
        setl statusline+=\ ⌨\ %{&fileformat}:\ %y
        setl statusline+=\ %{&fileencoding?&fileencoding:&encoding}\ %0*
    else
        setl statusline+=\%#StatusFileColour#
        setl statusline+=\ %f\ %m\ %=%0*
    endif
endfunction
```

- Inactive `statusline`

```
function! SttLine_Inactive(usesimple)
    setl statusline=

    if (!a:usesimple)
        setl statusline+=\%#StatusBlockGrey#
        setl statusline+=\ %{g:currentmode[mode()]}\ %0*

        setl statusline+=\%#StatusLineGrey#
        setl statusline+=\ %p%%\(%L)\ ≡\ L%l\:%c\ \|%0*

        setl statusline+=\%#StatusFileGrey#
        setl statusline+=\ [%{winnr()}]\ %f\ %m%=%0*

        setl statusline+=\%#StatusBlockGrey#
        setl statusline+=\ ⌨\ %{&fileformat}:\ %y
        setl statusline+=\ %{&fileencoding?&fileencoding:&encoding}\ %0*
    else
        setl statusline+=\%#StatusFileGrey#
        setl statusline+=\ %f\ %m\ %=%0*
    endif
endfunction
```

---

I then define some functions for different actions in vim, including `VimEnter`, `WinNew`, `WinEnter` and `WinLeave` as I want a different style for `netrw` window

- Function execute when vim start

```
function! SttLine_VimStart()
    let usesimple = (&filetype=="netrw") || (&filetype=="help")
    call SttLine_Active(usesimple)
endfunction
```

- Function that executes when a new window is opened:

```
function! SttLine_NewWin()
    let nWin  = bufnr("$")

    let iwin     = 0
    let hasnetrw = 0
    while (iwin < nWin)
        if (getbufvar(iwin, "&filetype") == "netrw")
            let hasnetrw = 1
        endif

        let iwin += 1
    endwhile

    if (hasnetrw>0)
        vert res
        vert res -25
    endif
endfunction
```

- Function executes on enter a window

```
function! SttLine_Enter()
    let usesimple = (&filetype=="netrw") || (&filetype=="help")
    call SttLine_Active(usesimple)
endfunction
```

- Function executes on leaving a window

```
function! SttLine_Leave()
    let usesimple = (&filetype=="netrw") || (&filetype=="help")
    call SttLine_Inactive(usesimple)
endfunction
```

---

Finally the augroup for those functions above

- `augroup` to call the *correct* `statusline`:

```
augroup Auto_Change_SttLine
    autocmd!
    autocmd VimEnter * call SttLine_VimStart()
    autocmd WinNew   * call SttLine_NewWin()
    autocmd WinEnter * call SttLine_Enter()
    autocmd WinLeave * call SttLine_Leave()
augroup END
```

---

- **To test the script**:

1. I open a file, let's call it file_01.txt from the terminal:
   `$ vim  file01.txt`
2. then in vim, I open another file, file_02.txt:
   `:new  file_02.txt`

- **My problem**

The first time, it worked as I expected. But for the next times I opened vim, it failed sometimes.

I realize that if I close file_02.txt before closing file_01.txt, the next time I start vim, my script fails.

In order to fix it, I need to close file_01.txt before closing file_02.txt.

- **My question**

What is causing this problem and how to make my script work regardless of the previous closing order?

Here is my youtube [video](https://youtu.be/Q371SZrwR50) demonstrating the steps I did to produce the error.

---

- **Additional information**

Below are the highlight I used for my statusline

```
hi StatusBlockColour    cterm=bold ctermfg=235 ctermbg=190
hi StatusBlockGrey      cterm=bold ctermfg=235 ctermbg=247
hi StatusLineColour     cterm=bold ctermfg=190 ctermbg=240
hi StatusLineGrey       cterm=bold ctermfg=245 ctermbg=240
hi StatusFileColour     cterm=bold ctermfg=208 ctermbg=240
hi StatusFileGrey       cterm=bold ctermfg=245 ctermbg=240
```

---

- **Update 1**
  I just found some other issues in my `.vimrc`. I used

```
au BufWinLeave * mkview
au BufWinEnter * silent loadview
```

to restore the last view. It accidentally enabled me to run `SttLine_Enter()` and the result is bad.

Recently I added to my augroup a new `au` for `BufWinEnter`, so it became:

- (Updated) `augroup` to call the `statusline`:

```
augroup Auto_Change_SttLine
    autocmd!
    autocmd VimEnter    * call SttLine_VimStart()
    autocmd WinNew      * call SttLine_NewWin()
    autocmd BufWinEnter * call SttLine_Enter()
    autocmd WinEnter    * call SttLine_Enter()
    autocmd WinLeave    * call SttLine_Leave()
augroup END
```

Comment: Do you use views?

Comment: what is views. I'm quite new to vim.

Comment: `:help View`, and also check `:set viminfo?` maybe. I'm just trying to think of things that could be automatically restoring state; normally, very few thing can affect vim between instances. See also [How to debug my vimrc](https://vi.stackexchange.com/q/2003/10604)

Comment: @D.BenKnoble I just found out that it has something to do with `mkview` and `loadview`. My `autocmd` for setting up a sttline for newly opened window works because of those commands, but unfortunately they also cause the unexpected behaviour I post. I'll take a look to View and viminfo as you suggest to see if there is a work around to prevent the "negative" effect of `mkview` and `loadview`. I updated my post too.